# SU Permission Denied Despite of ABD Root on Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xamarin

I wanted to write commands to SU like this:

```
Java.Lang.Process process = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su");
```

I get the following error unfortunately:

```
'Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied'
```

I have ran `adb root` and I have access to shell right now but this error keeps popping up. I'm using Xamarin.Android and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb root` is not the same as having a rooted device where you can access the `su` command. There is a reason as to why the command is only available using Android Debug Bridge (adb) on emulators.

You can use `su` on devices that are rooted. I wrote a blog post about how to do this with Xamarin here: https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2018/07/xamarin-and-java-processes.html

Instead of using `Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec()` to start the process, you can use `ProcessBuilder` instead, which allows you to build the command nicely like and await the result like:

```
var builder = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "hello");
var process = builder.Start();
var exitCode = await process.WaitForAsync();
```

For starting some process as root you can do:

```
var builder = new ProcessBuilder("su", "-c", "echo hello");
```

However, doing this does not change the fact that the Emulator you are using is not rooted as devices would be. So none of this will work as you expect.

If you are looking to root your emulator, like a device would be rooted. You would need to install something like SuperSU or Magisk on your AVD. This is very well described here: https://medium.com/@anthony.f.tannous/android-10-emulation-of-magisk-supersu-on-an-aosp-avd-de93ed080fad

This will involve:

1. Acquiring root using `adb root`
2. Mounting the `/system/` partition
3. Pushing some files which override the `su` and other binaries with patched ones
4. Starting a SU daemon

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I'll check it out. As soon as I get the access, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.
Thanks again.

Comment: I actually get "Root Undetected" error in SuperSU. Any suggestions over this?

Comment: Did you mount the file system and copy the contents as described?

Comment: I did everything step by step but I unfortunately get that error.